# How to run Ionic app on android-studio with capacitor on Ubuntu?

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, capacitor

When I run the `ionic capacitor run android` command, to launch my application in Android Studio, I get the error saying:

> Unable to launch Android Studio." You must configure "linuxAndroidStudioPath" in your capacitor.config.json to point to the location of studio.sh, using JavaScript-escaped paths:
>       example:
>       {
>         "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
>       }

but I configured the path my **capacitor.config.json** but the error persists.

[image]

Here's my capacitor.config.json file

[image]

Comment: Have you find anything for this problem yet? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 26):

First, run `whereis android-studio` in your terminal. This command will return the path of your android studio.

Mine is `/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`. I installed android-studio from the ubuntu software store. Maybe you installed it through a different source and in a different location.

Then add `"linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"` in capacitor.config.json which is located in the root of your project.

Replace `/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` by your path. which is returned to you by `whereis android-studio`

Comment: `whereis android-studio` returned `/snap/bin/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` adding this to `linuxAndroidStudioPath` didn't help, but adding `/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` to `linuxAndroidStudioPath` worked

Comment: What if you are using  Typescript instead of JSON for Capacitor configuration file (`capacitor.config.ts`) ?  It doesn't seem to have a property for this setting in the `CapacitorConfig` interface.  [`CapacitorConfig` interface docs can be found here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config)

Comment: `whereis android-studio` failed for me. I rather had to do `whereis studio`

Answer (score 5):

I use **JetBrains Toolbox** and **macOS**

to open the capacitor project with Android Studio with `npx cap open android` I had to export the Android Studio path as follow:

```
export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH="/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/201.7199119/Android Studio.app"
```

Answer (score 3):

`"linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"` is the path.

Add sudo when running the project `sudo npx cap open android`

Answer (score 2):

in my case, android studio location was "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"

```
{
  ...
  "linuxAndroidStudioPath": "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set environment variable--

Step1- Run: **nano ~/.bashrc** in terminal.

Step2- Add **export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH="path of android-studio/bin/studio.sh"** in .bashrc file.

Step3- Run **npx cap open android** in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I didn't manage to find out why it can't verify the path for android studio.

In order to use `npx cap open android` i had to open Android Studio before running the command.

Answer (score 0):

- Open your terminal and run `gedit .bashrc`.
- Set the environment variable:

  ```
  export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH="path of android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
  ```
- Save your file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

This will read your capacitor directly by running

> Ionic cap open android

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers here are on point, however I would like to add something small to note.

Its worth noting that Android Studio has different installation locations depending on the distribution you are using and also some installations are command-line based others are offline installations.

Some well known places are:

- /usr/local
- /usr/share
- /opt

Lastly whereas the commands to search for android-studio may work in some instances where the default installation path was not changed. However the command

> whereis android-studio

will not return anything in a case where the directory name is not the default i.e

/opt/android-studio-2021.2.1/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"

or

/usr/local/android-studio-2021.2.1/bin/studio.sh"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this: In Ionic 6x, there's no `capacitor.config.json`. You'd have to set an environment variable of `CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH` globally. Do this by typing

```
export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH=/path/to/android-studio/studio.sh
```

Worth noting that my Android Studio is found at `/opt/android-studio/bin` and not under `/snap/...`

Answer (score -1):

Everything looks correct so the likely answer is that you have got the path wrong somehow.

Could you recheck it?

Also, are you running the latest versions of everything?